# Accessing many-to-many set field in django relation

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a set of models similar to that below, where a person can be a member of many clubs, but have a different membership type. In this instance, I consider `Membership` to be a [weak entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity) of `Club`

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Club(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
            Person,
            related_name="clubs"
            through='Membership'
            )

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club)
    member_type = models.TextField()
```

I know that I can access the membership details from a club by going:

```
instance_of_club.membership_set.all()
```

And I can get a listing of all the people by using this:

```
instance_of_club.membership_set
```

However, I am trying to write a serialiser for this sort of scenario and am having trouble correctly finding the "membership" details from the django `Meta` class.

`Club._meta.many_to_many` gives the `members` field:

```
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: members>
```

But nothing on `members` gives any indication on how to get the `_set` accessor - and I need to be able to get these programatically. What I want is to be able to get a list of all ManyToMany `through` relations, and then get the objects these hold and not just the foreign objects.

For context:

- `members.related.through` gives the `Membership` class, but not a collection of instances
- `members.related.related_name` gives nothing
- `Club._meta.get_all_field_names()` gives `membership` in the list, but not `membership_set`

How can I get a list of the `through` relation objects on a ManyToMany field?

Comment: As per my understanding, the through model in this case `through='Person'` should be `through='Membership'`?

Comment: Yes, thanks :) That was an error in transcription.

Comment: Why the m2m relationship is on `Member` model while the `Membership` through table has a foreign key to `Person` model? How `Member` and `Person` models are related?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Club` model should probably look like:

```
class Club(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person, related_name='clubs', through='Membership'
    )
```

> I know that I can access the membership details from a club by going:
>
> ```
> instance_of_club.membership_set.all()
> ```
>
> And I can get a listing of all the people by using this:
>
> ```
> instance_of_club.membership_set
> ```

This is not true! `instance_of_club.membership_set` is a club's related manager for the `Membership` model. `instance_of_club.membership_set.all()` is this related manager's `QuerySet` (too, of `Membership` model instances):

```
club_instance.members.all()  # all related Person instances of a club
club_instance.membership_set.all()  # all related Memberships of a club
person_instance.clubs.all()  # all related Club instances of a person
person_instance.membership_set.all()  # all related Memberships of a person
```

Comment: I know I can get the through model, I dont need that. I need the field on the original object.

Comment: `club_instance.members.all()` will just return a list of people not membership objects

Comment: What is the problem then? You mention `club_instance.membership_set.all()` which gives you a QuerySet of the through instances

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Updated my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: This serializer is running across a number of different models. I need to be able to get the many to many through relationships in a similar way to accessing `fiels.many_to_many`